# How to return multiple set-cookie headers from AWS Api Gateway while using HTTP endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, setcookie

I have an api gateway configured with an existing HTTP endpoint( running on flask ) which returns signed cookies in header hence I need to set multiple set-cookie header.

The multi value headers provided by aws works for lambda but I don't know how to make it work with http endpoint.

I tried some other option like passing through set-cookie headers but it only passes only one header out of all the headers.

I tried to fold the headers into a single header like

```
resp.headers['set-cookie'] = 'cookie1=value1;path=/, cookie2=value2;path=/
```

But this does not work as browser is not able to read this properly.

Comment: Does it help with bypassing headers? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html

Comment: @nickolay.laptev No it doesn't as api gateway is simply neglecting all the cookies except the last one, api-gateway is expecting the header to be unique

Comment: I have the same problem.  My Flask app needs to send back multiple cookies, but only one passes to the browser